# Can I pin a label inside another label to create a border?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, uilabel

In an effort to create a border effect, I  would like to pin one label inside another with, say, the following constants:

```
up - 5
left - 5
right - 5
down - 5
```

This would give me a 5-point border around the inside label. Is this possible? If so, how do I make this happen? Or is there a better way to create a border around a text label?

Comment: Could you please draw it in a paper and attach a snapshot of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific needs, I would suggest using a border on the `UILabel` itself, by using the following code:

```
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
label.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

Or Objective-C:

```
[label layer].borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
[label layer].borderWidth = 2;
```

As a response to your comment on the other answer:

When you pin a view to another view in the storyboard, it only creates a view with the parameters it guesses to be what you want. Usually this is correct, but if you need more fine-grained control over what attributes it links, you can select the constraint, and in the inspector change all it's properties (except first and second item):

[image][image]

But I would advise against using a `UILabel`, just to set a background. If you really need to use a view behind the label, use a simple `UIView`, so that iOS doesn't have to calculate letter spacing and such and keep information about the label's text. This one instance of a label versus an empty view might not make a difference, but a developer should always aim to use their memory and CPU wisely.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time and effort to explain and clarify this for me, for it really helps! I agree with your very first solution, that setting the properties programmatically is the best route to take. My code ended up being:

    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    label.layer.borderWidth = 1

Thanks again for  pointing me in  the right direction; I suspected that there was a simple solution to my question.

Comment: @SillyGoof No problem, be sure to mark the answer if correct and upvote it if you liked it! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If your application is storyboard based, here is one option you can do. Simple drag in an image and put it behind the label. Just make the image whatever style border you prefer. If you want to put the image in front of the label, make sure to make the middle of the image transparent.

For something as easy as a border you do not need any photo editing software, you could just use something like Microsoft Powerpoint. Good luck, hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboard to lay it out. The first, bigger label is blank with a solid color, and the second, smaller one is a text label with a different color and a title. When I try to control-drag from the smaller label into the large one, it only gives me options to pin the leading and trailing edges to the outer label, and even this doesn't work correctly.